# Material UI centering a Link element

Tags: css

I am editing my question because I thought it was perhaps too broad and involved and I do want to respect the time of my colleagues here. So I thought I would just focus on a particular aspect of my roadblock and figure the rest out from there.

I am new to the Material UI library and I am struggling getting a `<Link>` element to be centered in the mobile view.

I have tried all the props on the MUI docs regarding centering.

This is the mobile view:
[image]

I have tried `textAlign="center"`, `justifyContent="center"`, `justify="center"` in both the `<link>` element and inside the `classes.link`.

That forgot password is not budging. Any guidance towards a solution on why none of the above is working and what would work or what to look for would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps pass `justify-content: center;` to the `div` element wrapping the Link?

This is how the Link is shown centered in [the Material UI documentation.](https://material-ui.com/style/links/)

[image: material-ui Link within div]

Comment: Thank you for your answer and it may just be a solution, however, I will be offering the solution I found and perhaps it may help others as MUI posts on SO are not easy to come by.

Comment: Ethan, I accepted your answer because it was what I ended up doing except that I had to add `<Typography>` element as a wrap, the link element had no wrap at the time. It probably would have been helpful to post that code. Anyway, I went with `<Typography>` as the wrapper to link because it was that API that was keeping me from centering it. When I added MUI Typography element as a wrap, I was able to take away its ability to have that control over the link element, I overrode it.

Answer (score 0):

Answering to a old post in case it helps someone.
This is written using `React 17+` and `MUI 5`. `Box` component is obviously optional.

```
<Box sx={{ p: '10px 0px' }}>
    <Typography align='center'>
        <Link href='#'>
            Your Text Here
        </Link>
    </Typography>
</Box>
```